# PHPMyAdmin - URL to row-editing page

Tags: mysql, url, phpmyadmin

Is there a way to create URL to PHPMyAdmin to page where I can edit a row?

Something like `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/database/table/id=123/edit`

There is a hint in PHPMyAdmin FAQ how to create link to database or table pages, but not to a specific row. If I look at the URL of the page where I can edit a row, there are no information about ID, only some wild tokens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, sorry, this isn't something that phpMyAdmin has implemented. Your choices at this point are to use phpMyAdmin to get to the proper table and do the rest by hand (as you have seen through the FAQ) or to write your own custom bit of PHP (or Python, C, Perl, Brainf*ck...) to handle editing a particular row.

Comment: Of course, you're also welcome to add a feature request https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/feature-requests/ .